# show a sum of a specified ressource in a column

Tags: ms-project

I have a project that is working fine.
Anyway i want to show a column with the sum of a particular ressource.
Let me explain with example.
i have a tasks that uses distances. i insert for each task a certain amount of distance.
ex
Mission 1
task 1 100km,
task 2  120 km,
task 3 50km

Mission 2
task 1 60km
task 2 70km

i need to show in a column the amount of km of each task and in the parents (mission 1 and mission 2) the sum of its children task.

thank you in advance for any help

Comment: Distances are stored in a number column like Number1 and you want the parent task to show the sum of the distances?

Comment: Distances are stored in Ressources.

Comment: the ressource is named Fuel (price/km) and cost is 1 dollar/km. When i add a task, i assign the ressource Fuel in it with the number of kms.

Comment: Add the Cost field to the Gantt chart. If you have a task with 100 units of the fuel resource assigned and the fuel resource costs $1, the Cost field will show $100. The summary task (Mission) will show the aggregated costs for all subtasks.